# Insert new record using a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, linq-to-sql, insertonsubmit

Is it possible to insert a new record where the values are stored in a dictionary instead of a structure? I've seen this code:

```
Dim ord As New Order With _
{.OrderID = 12000, _
 .ShipCity = "Seattle", _
 .OrderDate = DateTime.Now}

' Add the new object to the Orders collection.
db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(ord)
```

but I have 250 odd values/fields to add to a datatable for each record and would prefer to use a dictionary rather than define all the column fields and add values in a class like the example above. Can this be done?

```
dim dctValues as new dictionary(of string,integer)
key="val" & x
'loop through calc and increase x from 1 to 250
'key goes from "val1" to "val250"
dctValues.add(key,999)
...etc for 250 fields/columns for one record
db.Orders.InsertonSubmit(dctValues)
```

Comment: That is depends on what is in the InsertonSubmit, but maybe no. Maybe you want to use For Each loop?

Comment: tks Ian, I'm not an expert, but the insertonsubmit will just contain a single record consisting of 250 odd column values. A for each loop could work, can you post an example please?

Comment: Ok, sure. =) I added code example in my answer. You seem to have multiple items in your `Order`. Thus, your `class` which you put in your dictionary should not be `integer` but you should declare a kind of class like `MyNewClass` which captures all the elements in the `Order`

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `List`, which may be better suited for your case, since you don't seem need to have `key` of your `Order` at all (as long as you can submit it) - that is you only need the `Value` of the `Dictionary` (at least that is the impression I got from your code). Maybe then, `List` would be a better choice for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the `InsertOnSubmit` works well for every item in your dictionary, you could call it by `For Each` Loop like this

```
For Each item As MyNewClass In dct.Values
    db.Orders.InsertonSubmit(item)
Next
```

The more difficult part would be to define `MyNewClass` and put that in your Dictionary to later process it easily

```
Dim dctValues As New Dictionary(Of String, MyNewClass) 'Note the Value is MyNewClass
```

Edit:

Using `List`, you will have to have first your `MyNewClass` still declared somewhere and takes care of three variables `OrderID`, `ShipCity`, and `OrderDate`.

```
Public Class MyNewClass
    Public OrderID As Integer
    Public ShipCity As String
    Public OrderDate As Date
End Class
```

But now you do not need to put the `Key` when adding item:

```
Dim list As List(Of MyNewClass) 'List declaration, later will have 250 items
```

Then for each object you have, first put them in your `List` by `for loop` then put that to the data base with

```
For Each item As MyNewClass In list
    db.Orders.InsertonSubmit(item) 'no need to submit per item, but using For Each loop
Next
```

Edit 2 (from comments):

If it is a `DataTable` we may still parse it (as one `DataTable` implies multiply data of the same `class`). To solve it, I think it is best still to declare a class which represents a row in your data table. But one row in your case is 250 columns. This is a lot. And there is no way to put the row correctly unless we know what is the type of each data. But since the number of data column is quite a lot, I could further suggest you to do one of the following two alternative options:

**First way** is to split the table into multiple tables whose data relation is in the Third Normal Form (please find more about this). This way you minimize the size of the data and will have good structure of the data relation. This way will make you end up with several smaller tables, but that's worth doing for sustainability and expandability. The only cost of Third Normal Form that people consider is usually the query speed. But 100 records of 250 columns will not produce this issue.

**Second way** is by using column info of your data table to get the data types for each individual column. Though the number of columns are plenty, the number of data type is more limited. Then, you need to create a generic way to map each data type to the produce data of equivalent type in C#. Then for all data in the 250 columns, you use this generic class' method to translate it to VB.Net datatype & vice versa according to your process.This method is more efficient and enduring, yet you might find a little trouble creating the generic class. But this way you don't need to change your table

Why normally people fix this issue more structurally with the **second way** is because of the **reusability**. Given new case with X columns and Y records, the previous solution can be used for new problem. But if you play with **this one set of data a lot more**, having the **first way** is not a bad choice. Alternatively, if neither the first nor the second suits your situation, then yes, you could take some pain to declare a `class` with 250 members

Comment: tks Ian. If I use a dictionary as you show it looks like I need to create new class called ``MyNewClass`` which will contain all 250 items. Isn't this back to the first problem? The table does contain a primary key, but so far the code inserts a new record correctly. Please can you show me how to use a ``list``?

Comment: No, what I meant was you should not create `Dim dctValues As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` but rather `Dim dctValues As New Dictionary(Of String, MyNewClass)` using Dictionary. The dictionary `MyNewClass` itself only contains **one** order. You have 250 instances of `MyNewClass`. Each `MyNewClass` consists of `OrderID`, `ShipCity`, `OrderDate` (3 variables). If you only use `Integer`, you can only store 1 variable. If you use `List`. You also need to create `MyNewClass`, except that you do not need to have the key "val1", "val2" etc.

Comment: tks Ian. I can see what you mean. But I have 250 odd items/fields like ``city, zip, name, order, surname``  etc in a single record, not 250 records with 3 fields named ``orderid. shipcity, orderdate``. I think you answer assumes 250 records with 3 fields? sorry if my question was unclear

Comment: Ow, that could troublesome depends on: How does your record look like? Strings? Then, it is more like the problem of parsing the record than using `Dictionary` or `List`

Comment: no its a long list of integers and doubles! Groups of categories consisting of 21 variables per group, 10 odd groups. What do you mean by ``parsing``?

Comment: Ok, and this long list of integers and doubles are contained in...? List of something? file? DataTable? What are the container of all the records?

Comment: A datatable. I was unsure whether to create a datatable for each category, but decided to have one large datatable for all variables, I'm not sure if this is the best method? Datatable will ultimately have approx 100 records with 250 columns

Comment: I see, if it is a `DataTable` we may still parse it (as one `DataTable` implies multiply data of the same type). To solve it, I think it is best still to declare a class which represents a **row** in your data table. But one row in your case is 250 columns. This is a lot. And there is not way to put the row correctly unless we know what is the type of each data. But since the number of data column is quite a lot, I suggest you to do one of the following two options:

Comment: **First way** is to split the table into multiple tables whose data relation is in the `Third Normal Form` (please find more about this). This way you minimize the size of the data and will have good structure of the data relation. This way will make you end up with several smaller tables, but that's worth doing for sustainability and expandability. The only cost of `Third Normal Form` that people consider is usually the query speed. But 100 records of 250 columns will not produce this issue.

Comment: **Second way** is by using column info of your data table to get the data types for each individual column. Though the number of columns are plenty, the number of data type is more limited. Then, you need to create a generic way to map each data type to the produce data of equivalent type in C#. Then for all data in the 250 columns, you use this generic class' method to translate it to VB.Net datatype & vice versa according to your process.This method is more efficient and enduring, yet you might find a little trouble creating the generic class. But this way you don't need to change your table

Comment: As for another alternative would be to find **non-basic** tool (advance) tool to do either the first or the second way more easily. But as for this tool, I have to apologize, because I do not know any. Yet, hope that my comments can give you some direction.

Comment: thanks Ian. I'll do some research on Third Normal Form. I do know in advance what the type of each column will be, so maybe take the pain once and declare a class with 250 items? Even if I break the table into 10 new smaller tables I'll still have to declare classes for each table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99741/discussion-between-zeus-and-ian).

Comment: @Zeus I add something in the chat

Comment: @Zeus The way you add an item to the dictionary is wrong. To add something to the dictionary, you should do dctValues.Add("SPOT1", yourClassName)